# Layout will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

Im trying to customize the layout of pagination on will_paginate to keep this way:

> << 1,2...5,6,7...23,24 >>

And, with this code:

```
<%= will_paginate @user_notifications, :params => {:order => params[:order], :type_order => params[:type_order]}, :container => false, inner_window: 1, outer_window: 1 %>
```

I got this:

[image]

But this layout shows only when I select the 6th page. When I'm on 5th page or less the layout turns to this:

[image]

How can I keep the layout always with two pages, then three pages and then two pages again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `:inner_window` and `:outer_window` options described here: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers.rb

Do this for desired effect:

```
<%= will_paginate stuff, inner_window: 1, outer_window: 2 %>
```

Also, try to remove the `container: false` call and see if your layout is now respecting the inner_window call.